# How to add an OnClickListener on a ShinobiChart graph

Tags: android, android-fragments, shinobi

I'm using ShinobiCharts in a project to draw graphs. The library draws graphs in a ChartFragments. I have an activity with two frame layouts and I'm adding chartfragments to each one. I've added click listeners to these frame layouts but they do not register an event. Is there a way to add an onClickListener to a frame layout that contains a fragment?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:clickable="true"` to the XML of those layouts?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and also setting `android:focusable=true`

Comment: The problem might be in the layout... Please share fragment(s) and activity layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `Fragment` classes:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
             // do whatever you want here
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** Since the library in question doesn't allow access to the XML layout, [W.K.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821110/w-k-s) implemented it using `OnGestureListener` and `onSingleTouchUp()`.

Comment: try making the root ViewGroup of the fragment layout clickable and focusable

Comment: I don't have access to that layout, that's handled by the library and basically it draws the charts on a canvas

Comment: hmm ... then it may not be possible to do it this way. Doesn't the library supply some sort of click events for its graphs ??

Comment: It's possible to set a OnGestureListener and implement the onSingleTouchUp() method